# Elastic Search: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.log4j.LogManager

Tags: elasticsearch, log4j, slf4j

Got below error when upgrade elastic search from 1.7 to 2.3.3

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.log4j.LogManager
        at org.apache.log4j.Logger.getLogger(Logger.java:104)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.logging.log4j.Log4jESLoggerFactory.newInstance(Log4jESLoggerFactory.java:38)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.logging.ESLoggerFactory.newInstance(ESLoggerFactory.java:82)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.logging.ESLoggerFactory.getLogger(ESLoggerFactory.java:66)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.logging.Loggers.getLogger(Loggers.java:121)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.settings.Settings.<clinit>(Settings.java:63)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had few log4j jars and slf4j jars in classpath but Elastic search tries to load log4j logger by default if it is available in classpath. For some conflicts log4j did not work for me. So forced Elasticsearch to use slf4j logger while creating client.

ESLoggerFactory.setDefaultFactory(new Slf4jESLoggerFactory());

Answer (score 0):

i resolved the same issue by adding below dependecies in POM.XML:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.2</version>
    </dependency>
```